# regular expression to check for spammer

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out the regular expression for preg_match() that would return true for all of the following scenarios:

1- strip spaces for people doing this "check out my website . com (no spaces)"

2- find the obvious "mywebsite.com" in "check out mywebsite.com"

3- find dot replacement "check out mywebsite dot com (no spaces)"

4- be case insensitive

Comment: i've currently only been able to do it with str_replace to replace spaces and " dot "   and then do the preg_match("#mywebsite.com#i",$strReplaceResult)

Comment: The PCRE modifer 'i' solves #4. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php 

What are you trying to actually match "check out my TEXT.com", with optional space between any of those words?

Comment: what my goal is, is i want to make a database of known website spammers and loop through them with $domain and put through a regex test to determine if the input field returns true for being spam for $domain... that is my ultimate goal. i suppose the str_replace and preg_match method will work but i was wondering if it can all be done with one regex

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I think you'll have to modify this in the future but for a rough implementation (what you've asked for) it should work. I also presumed your "check out my" is required text if not that can be removed. The `\s*` means any amount of whitespace; the `\w*` means any number of word characters (a-z, 0-9, and/or underscore). The `|` means "or" and the `()` groups the two values that "or" should be affecting. If you have questions please ask. The outer most parenthesis group the potential domain. You may want to alter the `\w*` to `\w+` but I'd presume if they're saying "check out my .com" you'd also want to filter it...

```
if(preg_match('~check\s*out\s*my\s*(\w*\s*(\.|dot)\s*com)~i', $input, $domain)) {
     echo 'This is spam?';
}
```

A solution based on your actual code:

```
<?php
$spamCount=0;
$input=preg_replace(array('~\s*~', '~dot~i'), array('', '.'), 'Hi. Please see my website at "test domain . com" (no spaces) anothertest dot com');
$checkTheseDomains = array("testdomain.com","anothertest.com");
foreach($checkTheseDomains as $domain) {
    if(strpos($input, $domain) !== false) {
        $spamCount++;
    }
}
if($spamCount > 0){
        echo "Spam count of  <b>".$spamCount."</b>";
}else{
        echo "No spam";
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work on my tests. even if i removed the
    check\s*out\s*my\s* 
part, it doesnt seem to be testing anything in $domain specifically
http://pastebin.com/fAhZN5S8
returns "No spam" every time

Comment: That's not how the preg_match works; http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. The `$input` is what it is checking, `$domain` is what it captures. In your example you said "check out my" in this example you have "see my", those wont match.

Comment: @b747fp updated with an alternate solution, this work?